# ¿Por qué no aparecen los iconos de Fontastic?

Tags: css, html5

Estoy usando Sass y en la página de Fontastic agregué 6 iconos para que se incrusten en la página pero no aparecen. ¿Por qué sucede eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/H3XXN7wMjz3R3tuYbzimaZ/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

        <!--Redes sociales-->
        <div class="social-network">

            <a class="icon-facebook" href="https://facebook.com"></a>
            <a class="icon-twitter" href="https://twiter.com"></a>
            <a class="icon-youtube" href="https://youtube.com"></a>
            <a class="icon-linkedin" href="https://linkedin.com"></a>

        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El enlace de css arroja 404.

Comment: Funciona ese link https://file.myfontastic.com/H3XXN7wMjz3R3tuYbzimaZ/icons.css

??

Comment: Ese link me da Fontastic

Comment: Entonces envíale un ticket de soporte a Fontastic.

Comment: Soy novato. Como se hace?

Comment: No tengo ni idea, revisa en el sitio web de ellos.

Comment: Ando igual de perdio, no se me enlazan los iconos de fontastic

Comment: Así es aparentemente el problema esta en la web de la empresa, a simple vista esta todo correcto, el link las clases todo, te recomiendo usar iconos en SVG son mas manipulables y tenés el control total ya que el código lo tenés en tu archivo html por lo que no va a fallar a la hora de utilizarlos, te recomiendo [flaticon.com](https://www.flaticon.com/home) [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPtMn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPtMn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Si abres el [fichero que enlazas](http://ttps://file.myfontastic.com/H3XXN7wMjz3R3tuYbzimaZ/icons.css) podrás ver que el contenido es éste:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* cssdesdecero */
@font-face {
  font-family: "cssdesdecero";
  src:url("https://file.myfontastic.com/H3XXN7wMjz3R3tuYbzimaZ/fonts/1529835407.eot");
  src:url("https://file.myfontastic.com/H3XXN7wMjz3R3tuYbzimaZ/fonts/1529835407.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("https://file.myfontastic.com/H3XXN7wMjz3R3tuYbzimaZ/fonts/1529835407.woff") format("woff"),
    url("https://file.myfontastic.com/H3XXN7wMjz3R3tuYbzimaZ/fonts/1529835407.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("https://file.myfontastic.com/H3XXN7wMjz3R3tuYbzimaZ/fonts/1529835407.svg#1529835407") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: "cssdesdecero" !important;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "cssdesdecero" !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-icon-facebook:before {
  content: "\61";
}
.icon-icon-twitter:before {
  content: "\62";
}
.icon-icon-youtube:before {
  content: "\63";
}
```

Esto lo que hace es importar fuentes con iconos, indicar que los elementos que tenga el data-atributo `data-icon` o que tengan alguna clase que empiece con `icon-` deben usar esas fuentes. Y finalmente, se especifican los iconos para algunos casos especiales: facebook, twitter y youtube, que deberán tener las clases `icon-icon-facebook`, `icon-icon-twitter` e `icon-icon-youtube` respectivamente.

Y ahí es donde está el problema. En tu código estás usando las clases `icon-facebook`, `icon-twitter` e `icon-youtube` pero, quizás por algún error del sistema o por alguna entrada manual incorrecta, las clases "válidas" tienen `icon-icon`.

Si cambias eso en tu código, ya se ven los iconos:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/H3XXN7wMjz3R3tuYbzimaZ/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!--Menu Container-->
    <nav class="main-nav">
        
        <!--Redes sociales-->
        <div class="social-network">

            <a class="icon-icon-facebook" href="https://facebook.com"></a>
            <a class="icon-icon-twitter" href="https://twiter.com"></a>
            <a class="icon-icon-youtube" href="https://youtube.com"></a>
            <a class="icon-icon-linkedin" href="https://linkedin.com"></a>

        </div>

    </nav>
    
  </body>
</html>
```